# Manage permissions and passwords for linux, windows and mac

Tags: windows, linux, security, macos

I am searching some software to make something similar to a domain controller on windows that can be compatible with mac, linux and windows.

I need to apply security roles and manage their password and when to change.

Can be done with the windows domain controller? Someone have experience with another else?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Windows ActiveDirectory is implemented on top of the LDAP protocol and Kerberos protocols: both are supported under MacOS and Linux (although setup isn't as straightforward as under Windows).